# Odoo - alphabetical order in report

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am new to Python and Odoo, I am trying to learn how some of these loops work.
I created a report that allows me to print a list of registered members. But I don’t put them in alphabetical order on the PDF .

report.py

```
from openerp import api, models

class SportReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.event.report_partner'

    def method(self):
         return {
            'get_order':self._get_order,
         }

    def _get_order(self, obj):
         order_name = sorted(obj)
         return order_name


    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('event.report_partner')
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': self._ids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': self,
        }
        return report_obj.render('event.report_partner', docargs)
```

report.xml

```
<span t-raw="get_order(r.partner_id.lastname)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you report_partner order by the you can use _order.

```
class SportReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.event.report_partner'
    _order = 'report_partner asc'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but it did not change anything :/

Comment: that is the example of the order if you got the event members list then event.registration table order change.